# how to split multiple columns into multiple rows in sql (for school time table)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, jquery-ui

My table for school time table in mysql is like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SectionID|P1|P2|P3|P4|P5|P6|P7|P8|P9|P10|P11|P12|P13|P14|P15|P16|P17|P18|P19|P20........P35|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

per day 7 periods so 5 working days 35 periods in that table..

I want to display the data in daily time table view like

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|P1      |P2       |P3         |P4       |P5      |P6        |P7 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
p1data   p2data    p3data      p4data    p5data    p6data     p7data

p8data   p9data    p10data     p11data   p12data   p13data    p14data

p15data  p16data    p17data     p18data   p19data   p20data    p21data

..........................................................upto p35data
```

for 5 days using **JQUERY,PHP,MYSQL**
Note: don't display the column name for P8 to P35 in that display table.. day column while displaying time table is our wish..

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
  if(p.period=1, t.P1, if (p.period=2, t.P8, if (p.period=3, t.P15, if (p.period=4, t.P22, t.P29)))) as p1,
  if(p.period=1, t.P2, if (p.period=2, t.P9, if (p.period=3, t.P16, if (p.period=4, t.P23, t.P30)))) as p2,
...
from the_table t, 
     (select 1 as period
      union all
      select 2 as period
      union all
      select 3 as period
      union all
      select 4 as period
      union all
      select 5 as period) p
```

Join artificial table and place columns depending on period

Instead of the `if()` you can use `CASE/WHEN`

Answer (score 0):

Select Value  , Substring(FullName, 1,Charindex(',', p1)-1) as period,
Substring(p1, Charindex(',', p1)+1, LEN(p1)) as period
from Table1